# use d3js to convert buckets aggregation to an histogram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, histogram

I have a json of the following structure:

{"1": 35, "2": 12, ....}

The key is a number, and the value is an aggregation of that value from a collection in the db (another number).
There could be thousands of distinct keys.
I want to convert this aggregation to an histogram with maximum 10 buckets.
I want to use d3js library since we are already using it for other things.
It seems from the api that it just knows to accept an array of numbers, but i want to customize the values.

I just need an object and do not care about the visualization.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is already a histogram function for D3, if you go through the API I am sure you can find it. But since you want a custom solution something along these lines can work (I wrote it ad-hoc, so check it):

## VERSION 1 - single tick of event loop - synchronous

Let's create a sample dataset:

```
var x = {};
for (var i =0;i<1000;++i){
    x[i]=Math.random()
}
```

Create a function that will take an object, a number of buckets and a bucket interval:

```
function allocate(obj,bucketCount,bucketStep){
    var objLastIndex = Object.keys(obj).length - 1;
    var retValue = Array.apply(null,Array(bucketCount))
        .map(function(d,i){
            var obj = {};
            obj.count = 0;
            obj.freq = 0;
            return obj;
        });
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(d,i){
        var bucketIndex = obj[d]/bucketStep<<0;
        retValue[bucketIndex] && ++retValue[bucketIndex].count;
        if(i === objLastIndex){
            retValue.forEach(function(d,i){
                d.freq = d.count/(objLastIndex+1)
            })
        }
    });
    return retValue;
}
```

To use it:

```
allocate(x,10,0.1);
"[
    {
        "count": 84,
        "freq": 0.084
    },
    {
        "count": 90,
        "freq": 0.09
    },
    {
        "count": 113,
        "freq": 0.113
    },
    {
        "count": 98,
        "freq": 0.098
    },
    {
        "count": 111,
        "freq": 0.111
    },
    {
        "count": 108,
        "freq": 0.108
    },
    {
        "count": 108,
        "freq": 0.108
    },
    {
        "count": 82,
        "freq": 0.082
    },
    {
        "count": 108,
        "freq": 0.108
    },
    {
        "count": 98,
        "freq": 0.098
    }
]"
```

Or:

```
allocate(x,10,0.5);
"[
    {
        "count": 496,
        "freq": 0.496
    },
    {
        "count": 504,
        "freq": 0.504
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "freq": 0
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "freq": 0
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "freq": 0
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "freq": 0
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "freq": 0
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "freq": 0
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "freq": 0
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "freq": 0
    }
]"
```

## VERSION 2 - multiple cycles - async - handles >1000000 points

Since you have not provided any feedback or indicated an output, I assume the format in VERSION 1 is what you want.

Now I will modify the above function a bit. I'll devide it in 2, first part will return an object much like ES6 Promises or yield keyword return, the other part (attached on the first so it doesn't have to be created again and again) will do the heavy lifting. You can attach a callback if you want:

```
function allocate(obj,bucketCount,bucketStep,callback){
    var keys =  Object.keys(obj);
    var retValue = Array.apply(null,Array(bucketCount))
        .map(function(d,i){
            var obj = {};
            obj.count = 0;
            obj.freq = 0;
            return obj;
        });
    console.log(retValue)
    retValue.__parent = {result:retValue,done:false};
    allocate._iterate(keys,0,retValue,obj,bucketCount,bucketStep,callback);
    return retValue.__parent;
}
allocate._iterate = function(keys,iteration,buckets,obj,bucketCount,bucketStep,callback){
    var currentLoad = keys.slice(iteration*10000,++iteration*10000),
        currentLoadLength = currentLoad.length,
        currentLoadLastIndex = currentLoadLength - 1,
        length = keys.length;
    currentLoad.forEach(function(d,i){
        var bucketIndex = obj[d]/bucketStep<<0;
        buckets[bucketIndex] && ++buckets[bucketIndex].count;
    });
    if(currentLoadLength < 10000) {
        buckets.forEach(function(d,i){
                d.freq = d.count/length;
        });
        buckets.__parent.done = true;
        return callback && callback(buckets);
    } else {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(
            allocate._iterate(keys,iteration,buckets,obj,bucketCount,bucketStep,callback)
        );
    }
}
```

To use this (last argument is an optional callback that is passed the array as its first argument):

```
var x = {}; //1000000 keys, I could do more but chrome could not handle his own object.
for (var i =0;i<1000000;++i){
    x[i]=Math.random()
}
var returnValue = allocate(x,10,0.1,function(){console.log("done!")});
//{result: Array(10), done: false}
//after few seconds --> 'done!' is logged
returnValue.result;
//"[
    {
        "count": 100156,
        "freq": 0.100156
    },
    {
        "count": 100575,
        "freq": 0.100575
    },
    {
        "count": 100009,
        "freq": 0.100009
    },
    {
        "count": 99818,
        "freq": 0.099818
    },
    {
        "count": 99785,
        "freq": 0.099785
    },
    {
        "count": 100332,
        "freq": 0.100332
    },
    {
        "count": 99778,
        "freq": 0.099778
    },
    {
        "count": 99790,
        "freq": 0.09979
    },
    {
        "count": 99795,
        "freq": 0.099795
    },
    {
        "count": 99962,
        "freq": 0.099962
    }
]"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ibowenkenobi has a reasonable solution, but if you would prefer to leverage d3, rather than completely reinvent the wheel, you can.  [Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opp1p0eu/3/).

Keep in mind that `d3.histogram().thresholds()` is a little hard to predict; you suggest a number of buckets and it will pick an actual number close to that.  Inputing 10 resulted in 13 buckets, in this case.

```
function parseBaseTenInt(n) {
    return parseInt(n, 10);
}

function accumulateValueCounts(accumulator, currentValue) {
    return accumulator + data[currentValue.toString()];
}

function calcBinSum(bin) {
    return bin.reduce(accumulateValueCounts, 0);
}

var numbers = Object.keys(data).map(parseBaseTenInt);

var histogram = d3.histogram().thresholds(9);

var bins = histogram(numbers);
console.log('bins:', bins);

var binSums = bins.map(calcBinSum);
console.log('totals for each bin:', binSums);
```